# Quick question about nodeJs and rendering templates

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm learning the express framework for nodejs and am curious if I need a templating engine like ejs or pug to use the `res.render('index.ejs')` function to serve html.

It seems like when I tried to serve up a basic html page without the template, it failed when I navigated to the page, `res.render(index.html)`.

So I guess my question is, if I use `res.render()` in express, do i have no choice but to use a templating engine?

Comment: Have you read the docs on templating yet? https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html Jade comes by default but you can swap in any engine you like, as long as you define where the views are and which engine you're using.

Comment: Read the docs: [`res.render()`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.render) and [`res.send()`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.send)

Comment: Got it reading through them as we speak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use res.send file [found here](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile)
res.render is usually used to render a template via a template engine. 
So it is up to how you design the project - whether you send all your html code from server via a template engine - or use a client side app like angular .

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and they recommended me to try this

```
 app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
```

it did not work for me, but maybe it will work for you.